# How to integrate reCaptchaV3 in contact form?

Tags: php, html, validation, contacts, recaptcha-v3

First of i'm a big enthusiast but no profesional in any way, so i got some basic knowledge in coding.
I'm trying to integrate reCaptcha V3 in my existing contact form.
But i don't know if it's done right. I've been googling like a mad man but all the "How to's" are all doing something different. I added it yesterday using this example: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/example-of-how-to-add-google-recaptcha-v3-to-a-php-form--cms-33752 and got some 0.9 score results in the analytics but i'm still not really confident it works correctly.

I tested my score with this https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v3-request-scores.php which results in a score of 0.9
I tried changing the needed score to 1.0 on my own website but the submit still came through.

This is what i added to load the reCaptcha:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/contact.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="validate/css/style.css">
                                                                <!----- SITE KEY REPCAPTCHA ----->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=*****"></script>
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('******', {action: 'contact'}).then(function(token) {
       $('#contact').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' + token + '">');
       $('#contact').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact">');
       $('#contact').unbind('submit').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

The $('#contact') part give's an error in firefox console: ReferenceError: $ is not defined. But i found other pieces of code were this is also used so i guess it just works?

This is my complete contact form:

```
                <h1></h1>
                <br />
                <h2></h2>
                <h2></h2>
                    <?php
                        //init variables
                        $cf = array();
                        $sr = false;

                    if(isset($_SESSION['cf_returndata'])){
                        $cf = $_SESSION['cf_returndata'];
                        $sr = true;
                    }
                    ?>
                <ul id="errors" class="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">
                    <li id="info">Er zijn wat problemen met je bericht:</li>
                        <?php 
                            if(isset($cf['errors']) && count($cf['errors']) > 0) :
                            foreach($cf['errors'] as $error) :
                        ?>
                    <li><?php echo $error ?></li>
                        <?php
                            endforeach;
                            endif;
                        ?>
                </ul>
                    <p id="success" class="<?php echo ($sr && $cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">Bedankt voor je bericht!<br />Je hoort zo snel mogelijk van ons!</p>
                <form id="contact" method="post" action="validate/process.php">
                    <label for="name">Naam: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['name'] : '' ?>" placeholder="naam" />

                    <label for="email">Email: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['email'] : '' ?>" placeholder="naam@voorbeeld.nl"  />

                    <label for="telephone">Telefoon:</label>
                    <input type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone"  placeholder="0612345678" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['telephone'] : '' ?>" />

                    <label for="enquiry">Onderwerp: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select required id="enquiry" name="enquiry">
                        <option value="" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Maak keuze') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Maak een keuze..</option>
                        <option value="steppen" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Steppen') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Steppen</option>
                        <option value="walks" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Walks') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Walks</option>
                        <option value="sessions" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Privatewalks') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Persoonlijke begeleiding (Private walks)</option>
                        <option value="sessions" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Events') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Events</option>
                        <option value="foto" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Foto') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Foto's opvragen</option>
                        <option value="website" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Website') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Website</option>
                        <option value="overig" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Overig...') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Overig...</option>
                    </select>

                    <label for="message">Bericht: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Minimaal 20 karakters"><?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['message'] : '' ?></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Versturen" id="submit-button" />
                    <p id="req-field-desc">Velden met een <span class="required">*</span> zijn verplicht.</p>
                    <br />

               </form>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['cf_returndata']); ?>
                </div>
```

And this is my form validation file:

```
if( isset($_POST) ){

    //form validation vars
    $formok = true;
    $errors = array();

    //sumbission data
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = date('d/m/Y');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    //form data
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    //validate form data

    //validate name is not empty
    if(empty($name)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "U heeft geen naam ingevuld";
    } elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "Uw naam mag alleen letters en/of spaties bevatten";
    }

    //validate email address is not empty
    if(empty($email)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "U heeft geen email adres ingevuld";
    //validate email address is valid
    } elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "U heeft geen geldig email adres ingevuld";
    }

    //validate message is not empty
    if(empty($message)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "U heeft geen bericht ingevuld";
    }
    //validate message is greater than 20 charcters
    elseif(strlen($message) < 20){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "Uw bericht moet minimaal 20 karakters bevatten";
    }

    // reCaptcha V3 stuff
        define("RECAPTCHA_V3_SECRET_KEY", '*****');
        $token = $_POST['token'];
        $action = $_POST['action'];

    // call curl to POST request
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('secret' => RECAPTCHA_V3_SECRET_KEY, 'response' => $token)));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $arrResponse = json_decode($response, true);

    // verify the response
        if($arrResponse["success"] == '1' && $arrResponse["action"] == $action && $arrResponse["score"] >= 0.5) {
            // valid submission
            // go ahead and do necessary stuff
        } else {
            $errors[] = "reCaptcha you are a bot";
            // spam submission
            // show error message
        }

    //send email if all is ok
    if($formok){
        $headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        $emailbody = "";

        mail("",'',$emailbody,$headers);

    }
    //what we need to return back to our form
    $returndata = array(
        'posted_form_data' => array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'telephone' => $telephone,
            'enquiry' => $enquiry,
            'message' => $message
        ),
        'form_ok' => $formok,
        'errors' => $errors
    );


    //if this is not an ajax request
    if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
        //set session variables
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

        //redirect back to form
        header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}
```

I tried adding $formok = false; in the verify response section:

```
        if($arrResponse["success"] == '1' && $arrResponse["action"] == $action && $arrResponse["score"] >= 0.5) {
            // valid submission
            // go ahead and do necessary stuff
        } else {
    --------->      $formok = false;
                        $errors[] = "reCaptcha you are a bot";
            // spam submission
            // show error message
        }
```

But this results in a constant failure to submit.

I hope someone can shed some light on how i'm doing. Is this the way, should it work? or have i made some mistake's?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial and works well for me.
https://stevencotterill.com/articles/adding-google-recaptcha-v3-to-a-php-form

Just try and see if there is any problem with your code.

You should include the jQuery in your HTML to make $ working

```
The $('#contact') part give's an error in firefox console: ReferenceError: $ is not defined. But i found other pieces of code were this is also used so i guess it just works?
```